# How To Change Colours In Plotly 3D Scatter

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I'm learning how to plot 3D scatters on Plotly using their [example](https://plot.ly/python/3d-scatter-plots/) with my own data. [Sample here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-KyyVvWQoQROWdldmtmM2FTMG8/view?usp=sharing)

I can get the scatter to plot (it looks so cool) but I can't get the different data series points to appear as separate colours.

```
import plotly #load plotly for plotting
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly import tools
from plotly.graph_objs import * #all the types of plots that we will plot here
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode() # run at the start of every ipython notebook

trace1 = Scatter3d(
    x = res,
    y = lc,
    z = spent,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        color=["z","y","x"],  # set color to an array/list of desired values
        colorscale='Viridis',   # choose a colorscale
        opacity=0.8
    )
)


data = [trace1]
layout = Layout(
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=0
    )
)
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='3d-scatter-colorscale')
```

I've tried using other examples for separate sources [e.g. Cambridge Spark](https://cambridgespark.com/content/tutorials/eda-and-interactive-figures-with-plotly/index.html) but I just don't have the experience to figure out how to make it work.

I'm sure it's something simple that I've missed but can't see it.

Comment: Color needs to be an array/list with the same size as x/y/z. If you could share some of your data (or some other data), I am sure we can get something to work.

Comment: Hi @MaximilianPeters I've added the sample I'm using from a Google Drive above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I should've had one of my series as the marker point. In this case I used spent instead of a list of x, y, z

```
import plotly #load plotly for plotting
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly import tools
from plotly.graph_objs import * #all the types of plots that we will plot here
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode() # run at the start of every ipython notebook

trace1 = Scatter3d(
    x = res,
    y = lc,
    z = spent,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        color=spent,  # set color to an array/list of desired values
        colorscale='Viridis',   # choose a colorscale
        opacity=0.8
    )
)


data = [trace1]
layout = Layout(
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=0
    )
)
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='3d-scatter-colorscale')
```